# Xcode - Info.plist - corruption/not locating

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist

I have a Project that uses Charts (Daniel Gindi), more on that later.

When I try and Validate the project prior to an upload to the App store I got a message saying the Bundle Display Name is 399 which is > 255 chars therefore can't be processed. In fact it's <20.

It turns out that there is an Info.plist error/corruption.

If I move the Info.plist around to trick Xcode into allowing me to choose the new location of the plist it doesn't allow me to (after highlighting the new file location and picking choose).

[image]

[image]

When I try and compile I get the message below implying that the Charts Framework has a Info.plist that it cannot find? Why, and surely a Project only has one Info.plist?

```
ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/edward/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Solar123-bqjcnonskcyoyygfqcnuiojnqgiy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Charts.framework/Info.plist /Users/edward/Desktop/Charts-master/Source/Supporting\ Files/Info.plist (in target 'Charts' from project 'Charts')
cd /Users/edward/Desktop/Charts-master
builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/edward/Desktop/Charts-master/Source/Supporting\ Files/Info.plist -producttype com.apple.product-type.framework -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphoneos -requiredArchitecture arm64 -o /Users/edward/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Solar123-bqjcnonskcyoyygfqcnuiojnqgiy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Charts.framework/Info.plist

error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/edward/Desktop/Charts-master/Source/Supporting Files/Info.plist' (in target 'Charts' from project 'Charts')
```

How can I force Xcode to accept THE Info.plist location?

I am using Xcode Monterey 12.0 Beta (21A5268h) and Xcode 12.5.1 (12E507).

I notice that there is an Info.plist in Tests and UITests - is this correct?

Comment: Try Project Settings -> Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File.  You can give it an explicit path to your plist file there.

Comment: Did that, but good point. I think part of the problem is that when you "Choose Info.plist file location" it doesn't show up and you have to close down Xcode and then restart it to take effect. I was just closing the Project and then reloading it. I'll need to check my archives and see if Charts has an info.plist - I thought there was just one for the project.

Comment: Project Settings -> Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File points to  $(SRCROOT)/Supporting Files/Info.plist. Can find no reference to the charts Info.plist in Build Phases?

Comment: Assuming `Charts` is a old-school framework, it's `Info.plist` path would be set in the settings for the target/project that builds it.  If it's a Swift Package, SPM should take of it for you, though you might need to reset the package cache.

Comment: Done a Product/Clean Build Folder! Is that the same as reset the packaging cache? If I put a Charts Info.plist where it bellyaches that it can't find it and then Archive/Validate get error message saying "Bundle Display Name length in bytes of 400 exceeds the maximum permitted length of 255", which was my original problem (previous SO question). The Project points to its Info.plist and didn't realise that Frameworks have their own Info.plists which seem to be confusing the Validation and causing the error...

Comment: Resetting package cache is `File Menu -> Swift Package -> Reset Package Caches`, but is only applicable if you're using Swift packages (as opposed to traditional framework projects).  Regarding the `Info.plist` cache, you want to use a path relative to the project, meaning relative to the `.xcodeproj` file, so something like `MyApp/Info.plist` where the `MyApp` directory is in the same directory as your `.xcodeproj` file.